# Android Method overrides

Tags: java, android, overriding

I am in the process of switching my android development environment from my Mac to a new Ubuntu 11.04 system. Everything builds correctly with no errors on the mac, but after checking into and out of github I get an error on all of the @override onClick code complaining that I should remove the @Override. Does this make sense?

Here is error:
The method onClick(View) of type new View.OnClickListener(){} must override a superclass method

I get a very similar error on the run method of a Runnable as well.

Comment: Are you using the correct jdk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 1.5 JDK doesn't support @Override on interfaces. Use the 1.6 JDK.

Answer (score 0):

hi 
 in your Eclipse , follow those instructions  : 
goto : **Project** ==> **Properties** ==> **Java Compiler** ==> **Configure Workspace Settings** ( on top Right of the Window ) ==> **Compiler Compliance level** : Choose **1.6** == > Apply and then OK